# what's the difference between FileInputstream ans RandomaccessFile?

Tags: java

It seems that  RandomaccessFile can do what FileInputstream?
so when we should use FileInputstream instead of  RandomaccessFile?

Comment: You should probably read their javadoc (especially their introduction) to get their intended usage. In the general case, you shouldn't be using RandomAccessFile which is mainly there to access specific bytes of a file and grants the possibility to go back and forth in the file.

Comment: As far as i know, it should be that FileInputStream can only read data and you cant move in the file without reading the bytes before desired position. RandomAccessFile offer the posiblity to move in file without reading the bytes before and you can both read and write. Also here is a nice table
http://www.skytopia.com/project/articles/javaio.html

Comment: @Nogi you can still `skip()` forward with a `FileInputStream`

Comment: @Aaron sure, you can, but according to documentation FileInputStream skip() will read bytes before and then throw them away, and RandomAccessFile can move there without doing that, it will just move pointer.

Comment: @Nogi that's not the impression I got by reading the OpenJDK's windows implementation. Now my C is rusty (this is a native function, so no nice Java code), but from what I gather it only displace the cursor

Comment: The javadoc however says it "skip over and discards" the data, but I assume it only means that the data is not reachable anymore.

Comment: @Aaron Sure, it's not reachable anymore because it can't move back, but it has to load that data in some way to discard it, but we can argue as long as we can, but that documentation is not clear and you can understand that both ways from it.

Comment: Hu yeah, that's why I checked the source code of the class? Now it's only one implementation between others, but if it can be optimized in an implementation I don't see why all implementation wouldn't do it (unless the underlying OS makes it impossible).